# Enter Key string.byte number in Lua

Tags: string, lua

I use this to detect space in a string in Lua:

```
if string.byte(" ")==32 then blah blah
```

What is the return number (instead of 32) for enter key or new line in Lua?

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These numbers denote the ASCII codes for each character. [Here's a chart for future reference](http://www.asciitable.com/) (but only to 127, as extended ASCII  is not supported) so newline is 10.

You can also print a list with the following code:

```
for i=1,127 do
  print(i .. " = " .. string.char(i))
end
```

However, command characters (such as newline) are difficult to interpret.

Comment: I thought Lua might use other numbers, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can check them with the `\n` and `\r` characters.

```
> =string.byte '\r'
13
> =string.byte '\n'
10
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the number, but you could try finding it by printing `print(string.byte("\n"))`